# Minimum spanning trees: Graphs where the cut propery doesn't work.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

In minimum spanning trees, the cut property states that if you have a subset of vertices in a graph and there exists an edge that's the smallest in the graph and you have exactly one endpoint for that edge then there exists a MST that contains that edge.

So what if I have a graph that looks like this:

[image: cut property]

Now the cut does have only one endpoint for the minimum edge but not all the minimum edges will be on that graph. You could also say that there's technically two minimum edges on that end point but then there's no way you can make a cut such that only one minimum end point exists. So is there a way to modify the cut property so that a graph like this could have a cut as shown above and it will still be true?

Comment: The cut property does not apply in this example: in this cut-set, there is not an edge whose weight is *smaller* than all the other edges in the cut-set.

Comment: What do you mean smaller than all other edges. In my definition, the smallest edge in the graph has to have exactly one end point in the cut in order to be considered in the MST. I also realized that my example may not fit into my modified definition. I basically have to modify the cut property on any graph where the minimum edge appears multiple times. I found out that if the edge does have exactly one end point then that particular edge will be in the MST but what about the other minimum edges?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. The cut property says that if you take a subset $X$ of the vertices, and there is an edge $e\in \delta(X)=\{e\in E(G)\mid e=xy, x\in X, y\not\in X\}$ with the property that the weight of $e$ is strictly smaller than the other edges in $\delta(X)$, then $e$ must be contained in any MST. This is not saying that *all* edges of minimum weight  appear in a MST.

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is modify the cut property statement so that it's true even if the smallest edge appears multiple times.

Comment: And my idea for this is to say that the smallest edge e has to have exactly one end point and exactly one minimum edge coming out of the endpoint. Then we could say that the particular edge that was in the subset will appear in the MST but we can't say anything about any other edge. Again, I want to modify the cut property so it works for graphs that have multiple smallest edges.

Comment: @davidmah I think your property should use "a smallest edge", not "the smallest edge". That is, you can take any edge that is not bigger than any other edge, and you could construct a MST that contains that edge (but perhaps not any other that's also in the cut and of the same weight).